# Multiple transitivity of finite groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

I am reading about permutation groups in "Finite Group Theory", Isaacs. 
Here the exercise 8A.5:

> Let G act $k$-transitively on some set $\Omega$, and let $H=G_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha \in \Omega$. Let $\Delta$ be the sets of points in $\Omega$ that are fixed by $H$ (namely $Fix_H(\Omega)$). Show that $N_G(H)$ acts $r$-transitively on $\Delta$, where $r$ is the minimum of $k$ and $|\Delta|$.

If a group $G$ is $k$-transitive on $\Omega$ and $\alpha \in \Omega$, then the stabilizer $G_{\alpha}$ is $(k-1)$-transitive on $\Omega \setminus \{\alpha\}$, so in $\Omega \setminus \{\alpha\} $ there are no fixed points under $G_{\alpha}$, for $k \ge 2$. How the exercise should be?
Should I take $k=1$?

There is something that I don't understand.

Comment: I think you are right. Even when $k=2$ we have $\Delta = \{ \alpha\}$. So in fact the exercise only makes sense when $k=1$. But you can still attempt it in that case!

Comment: Yes of course $k=2$ it is not allowed. I just edited, thank you!
I'll try with $k=1$ and have a look of what happen!

Comment: Transitive actions are actions by right mult. on cosets of the stabilizer $H$ of one point. If $Hg$ is a $H$-fixed point then $Hgh=Hg$ for all $h \in H$, from this follows that $h^{g^{-1}} \in H$ for all $h \in H$. This means that $g \in N_G(H)$. This proves that the cosets fixed by $H$ are of the form $Hg$ with $g \in N_G(H)$, that is necessarily transitive on them.

Comment: But in this way the exercise seems to be trivial. Is there any generalization on $k$-transitivity that involves the stabilizer and its normalizer?

Comment: Yes, you have proved that $gHg^{-1} \le H$ which of course implies $gHg^{-1}=H$ provided that $H$ is finite. I suspect that Isaacs is assuming that the groups are finite (it is a book on Finite Group Theory!) I don't think the result is true in general if $H$ is not assumed finite, because it is possible for $gHg^{-1}$ to be a proper subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Yes, if $G$ is $k$-transitive then (assuming finiteness) the stabilizer of $k$ points acts $k$-transitively on its fixed point set, but the proof is pretty much the same.

Comment: Ok, but in this case is just substituting $\Omega$ with $\Omega'=\Omega^k$ the cartesian product, if I understand correctly.